# Format BigDecimal jsf 2.0

Tags: java, jsf-2, web, converters, bigdecimal

I'm new with jsf and i'm trying to format a BigDecimal in my jsf page.

Here is what i did:

```
<h:outputText value="#{entity.bigDecimalValue}"> 
   <f:convertNumber maxFractionDigits="15" minFractionDigits="15" groupingUsed="false" />
</h:outputText>
```

this with a really small number it works as expected (example: 0.0000000000001)

but with simple values like number 4 it display 4.000000000000000

¿How can i get rid of the useless zeros?

I just want it shows me the values in a simple way.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are setting minFractionDigits="15" then, it will always display the extra zeros, unless you change it. What happens to "0.0000000000001" when you remove minFractionDigits="15" ? doesn't it display correctly ?

Comment: A little bit of experimentation and you could've worked this one out yourself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> minFractionDigits="15"

If you don't want at least 15 fraction digits, don't specify a minimum of 15 fraction digits.